# CefSharp .Net Core 3.1 Runtime problem (PresentationFramework.pdb Not Loaded)

Tags: wpf, winforms, .net-core, cefsharp

I have downloaded CefSharp v: 83.4 from Visual Studio NuGet on .Net Core 3.1 WPF and Winform project and on runtime I get this Error:

*PresentationFramework.pdb Not Loaded*

*PresentationFramework.pdb contains the debug information required to find the source for the module PresentationFramework.dll*

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Reading this did the trick: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample

1. I needed to set the Platform property to x64 or x86; as otherwise it would be AnyCPU and the check in the .targets file of the NuGet package would fail.
2. Add the following to your csproj file into `<ItemGroup>` tag:

   ```
    //.Net Core csproj/vbproj WPF
    <Reference Update="CefSharp">
      <Private>true</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Update="CefSharp.Core">
      <Private>true</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Update="CefSharp.Wpf">
      <Private>true</Private>
    </Reference>

    //.Net Core csproj/vbproj WinForms
    <Reference Update="CefSharp">
      <Private>true</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Update="CefSharp.Core">
      <Private>true</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Update="CefSharp.WinForms">
      <Private>true</Private>
    </Reference>
   ```

That was it.